# parse complicate json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I get JSON object from Mongo DB. This is JSON.

```
**JSON**
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5265347d144bed4968a9629c"),
    "name" : "ttt",
    "features" : {
        "t" : {
            "visual_feature" : "t",
            "type_feature" : "Numeric",
            "description_feature" : "Time"
        },
        "y" : {
            "visual_feature" : "y",
            "type_feature" : "Nominal",
            "description_feature" : "Values to be mapped to the y-axis"
        },
        "x" : {
            "visual_feature" : "x",
            "type_feature" : "Numeric",
            "description_feature" : "Values to be mapped to the x-axis"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build a table from "features" attributes in JSON object.
How to access to "features" attributes (it is a sub json object)in javascript?  It is important to get values from "visual_feature", "type_feature" and "description_feature".
UPD
I have a solution.

```
  $.ajax({
                                url: VASERVER_API_LOC + '/visualization/' + visid + '/',
                                type: 'GET',
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                 data: tmp_object,
                                success: function(json) {   
                                    var result = [];                         
                                    var keys = Object.keys(json);
                                    keys.forEach(function (key){
                                    result.push(json[key]);
                                    });

                                    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                                    console.log(">>>  visual_feature  ==  " + result[i].visual_feature);
                                    console.log(">>> type_feature  ==   "  + result[i].type_feature);
                                    console.log(">>>  discription_feature  ==  " + result[i].description_feature);
                                    };

                                }
                            });
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: So... what have you tried so far? It's incredibly lazy to dump a set of requirements here waiting for someone to write code for you.

Comment: for (feature in data.features) console.log(features[feature].visual_feature)

Comment: they should create a subdomain: simplistic-json-questions.stackoverflow.com -- there are literally hundreds of these questions out there

Comment: thank you. I have a  own solutin.

Comment: You can replace your `forEach()` / `push()` with `map()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your JSON result is an object, loop through like this:

```
for (var feature in result.features) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(feature)) {
    // do table building stuff
    console.log(feature);
  }
}
```

If it's not an object, you'll do `JSON.parse(result)`

To access the child properties, you can do another `for` `in` loop inside.

Answer (score 1):

JSON creates normal Javascript objects.

You can access their properties just like those of any other object:

```
var myValue = myObject.features.x.visual_type;
```

Comment: Not all javascript environments parse JSON strings automatically

Comment: @Sammaye: are there _any_ that do so?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy No, I don't think so, though using a library can make it seem so

Comment: thank you. I have a solution.I have updated my topic